# What are some best practices for hosting a Jenkins server on the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, server, hosting

Does anyone have any recommendations for hosting platforms for a Jenkins Server? (I know the obvious one is AWS, but is there any over platforms with advantages over this)

Or any recommendations for best practices?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an [AWS Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/setup-jenkins-build-server/) to Setup Jenkins with best practices. There are several best practices when setting up Jenkins and as well as using Jenkins for you CI/CD pipeline.

- Use AWS EFS for Jenkins Home folder so that you can attach it to any Jenkins Server.
- Setting up, DNS/Static IP and SSL certificates for external access.
- Is access limitations should take place like allowing access only from specific IP range. These can be handled using AWS VPC Security Groups.
- Setting up Master and Slave Nodes for Build scalability.

These are some of the concerns you need to address. You can find more details on setting up Jenkins in [AWS Jenkins Whitepaper](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DevOps/Jenkins_on_AWS.pdf).

These are 
 -